# Save MAPI IMsgStore in IStream implementation

Tags: c++, com, mapi, istorage

I'm trying to create pst msg store using IMAPISession method:

```
pses_->OpenMsgStore(0, prows->aRow[0].lpProps[1].Value.bin.cb, (LPENTRYID)prows->aRow[0].lpProps[1].Value.bin.lpb, NULL, MDB_WRITE | MAPI_DEFERRED_ERRORS | MAPI_BEST_ACCESS | MDB_NO_MAIL, &tmpPtr);
```

It uses PR_PST_PATH property provided in prows.

But now I need to open pst file in memory, i.e. using IStream in-memory stream implementation.  someone tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.
More than that, you cannot even open a PST file with the read-only bit set or on a read-only meadia.

Comment: I know about read-only bit set. This is because of PST internal format (Nodes, BHT and so on). But why I can't provide IStream to save PST to it. An output file can be represented by IStream interface. I just want to write it not by path but by interface.